# Dispose pattern usage

Tags: design-patterns, dispose

I read these articles on [Dispose Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [Dispose Implementation](http://dave-black.blogspot.co.uk/2011/03/how-do-you-properly-implement.html). My question is when calling the virtual dispose(bool) method from the finalizer, why we only pass false to the method and release unmanaged resource? If we pass true, what will it break?

Also even we have implemented the IDisposble interface, it still relies on the developer to either wrap the code in the *using* block or to call Dispose() explicitly, in order for the Dispose() method to be invoked. What is the addon of the IDisposble interface, if the developer is not careful enough?

Answer (score 1):

From your first link:

> The Boolean parameter disposing indicates whether the method was
>   invoked from the IDisposable.Dispose implementation or from the
>   finalizer. The Dispose(bool) implementation should check the parameter
>   before accessing other reference objects (e.g., the resource field in
>   the preceding sample). Such objects should only be accessed when the
>   method is called from the IDisposable.Dispose implementation (when the
>   disposing parameter is equal to true). If the method is invoked from
>   the finalizer (disposing is false), other objects should not be
>   accessed. **The reason is that objects are finalized in an unpredictable
>   order and so they, or any of their dependencies, might already have
>   been finalized.**

Hope this helps.

Comment: But the second link implements the release of managed source when the condition is true, including unhook the events. In that case, if the finalizer calls teh dispose method and pass false to it, the event will not be unhooked and will result a memory leak, isn't it?

Comment: The Dispose pattern is just a guideline. Someone might have a valid reason to do otherwise, but personally I would follow the MS guideline on Dispose.